# It Was Working Earlier, But Somehow I Broke It

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

HTML:

```
<canvas id="cnvs" width=1 height=250 style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

JS:

```
//  Square size
var squareSize = 50;
//  Trail size (smaller number means more trail)
var globalAlpha = 0.0025;
//  Text
var text = "Lorem Ipsum";
console.clear();
var cnvs = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = cnvs.getContext("2d");
var windW = window.innerWidth;
cnvs.width = windW - 20;
var cnvsH = cnvs.height;
function MouseMove(XMouse, YMouse) {
    console.clear();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.fillRect(
        XMouse - 10 - squareSize / 2,
        YMouse - 10 - squareSize / 2,
        squareSize,
        squareSize
        );
}
function handler(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var pageX = e.pageX;
    var pageY = e.pageY;
    if (pageX === undefined) {
        pageX =
        e.clientX +
        document.body.scrollLeft +
        document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        pageY =
        e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
    console.log(pageX, pageY);
    MouseMove(pageX, pageY);
}
if (document.attachEvent) document.attachEvent("onmousemove", handler);
else document.addEventListener("mousemove", handler);
var loop = setInterval(function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.globalAlpha = globalAlpha;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, windW, CnvsH);
    ctx.font = "100px Arial";
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.fillText(text, windW / 2, cnvsH / 2);
}, 10);
```

What's Expected is a Square That Fades Away, With Text In The Center
The square is drawn correctly, but the fade doesn't happen, and the text doesn't appear.
I use codepen for my coding.
It was working, but I think I tried adding comments, and something I did while doing that broke it. I haven't graduated high school so I don't have any college experience and all my coding is self-taught and tutorials (Thanks w3schools.com)

Comment: "It Was Working Earlier, But Somehow I Broke It" isn't a good question title, please specify the problem in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code are 2 mistakes.

First:

"var cnvs = document.getElementById("canvas");"

Your ID is -  "var cnvs = document.getElementById("cnvs");"

And secound:

In your "var loop" there is a typo mistake for 
"ctx.fillRect(0, 0, windW, CnvsH);" it should be "cnvsH" and not "CnvsH".

right -> ctx.fillRect(0, 0, windW, cnvsH);

Gl and try to use a Debugger.